# Why do onParseEnd callback on nodejs multer not called when using ios to upload files?

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, file-upload, multer

I have implemented a server using nodejs and used multer for handling file uploading.

When I use Postman to upload a file, the file is successfully uploaded and the console log "upload image api" also appears.

However when I upload a file from iOS using Swift, although the file is also successfully uploaded, the console log "upload image api" and "Form parsing completed" never appear. This means that the callback onParseEnd is not called and I guess this is the reason why it freezes there and doesn't go to the "upload image api" part.

Why onParseEnd is not called when I use iOS to upload a file? Everything goes fine when I use Postman.

**Nodejs and Multer:**

```
router.post('/upload', multer({
  dest: './public/uploads/user/',
  onFileUploadStart: function (file,req,res) {
    console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...')
    return true;
  },
  onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
    console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path)
  },
  onParseStart: function () {
    console.log('Form parsing started at: ', new Date())
  },
  onParseEnd: function (req, next) {
    console.log('Form parsing completed at: ', new Date());
    // call the next middleware
    next();
    }
}), function(req,res,next){
    console.log("upload image api");

});
```

**iOS swift:**

```
var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let url = NSURL(string:url)
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = method
    request.setValue("Keep-Alive", forHTTPHeaderField: "Connection")
    request.setValue("Cache-Control", forHTTPHeaderField: "no-cache")

    // set Content-Type in HTTP header

    let boundaryConstant = "Boundary-\(NSUUID().UUIDString)";
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundaryConstant)"

    request.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let filename = "image.jpg"
    var body = NSMutableData()
    body.appendString("--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Type: \(dataType)\r\n\r\n")
    body.appendData(data)
    body.appendString("\r\n")
    body.appendString("--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n")
    request.HTTPBody = body

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        println("Response: \(response)")
        var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("Body: \(strData)")
        var err: NSError?
        var statusCode : Int = (response is NSHTTPURLResponse) ? (response as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode : 404

        var json : NSDictionary?
        if(statusCode == 204){
            json = NSDictionary()
        }else{
            json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as? NSDictionary
        }

        // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console
        if((err != nil)) {
            println(err!.localizedDescription)
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
            completed(succeeded: false, data: nil, statusCode: statusCode)
        }
        else {
            // The JSONObjectWithData constructor didn't return an error. But, we should still
            // check and make sure that json has a value using optional binding.
            if let parseJSON = json {
                completed(succeeded: true, data: json, statusCode: statusCode)
                return
            }
            else {
                // Woa, okay the json object was nil, something went worng. Maybe the server isn't running?
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                println("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
                completed(succeeded: false, data: nil, statusCode: statusCode)
            }
        }
    })

    task.resume()
```

The following is the appendString function using in the above swift code.

```
func appendString(string: String) {
    let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
    appendData(data!)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Alamofire and the problem is gone. 
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

```
Alamofire.upload(.POST, URLString: url, multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: data, name: key, fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        }, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { request, response, data, error in

                    println("Response: \(response)")
                    var json = data as? NSDictionary

                    println("Body: \(json)")
                    var statusCode : Int = (response != nil) ? response!.statusCode : 404
                    completed(succeeded: true, data: json, statusCode: statusCode)

                }
            case .Failure(let encodingError):
                completed(succeeded: false, data: nil, statusCode: 404)
            }
    })
```

If someone know the reason why the previous method does not work, please leave a comment. Thanks.